# Commutative ring conjecture?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a commutative ring where every element has a multiplicative norm $N$.

So if $a,b,c$ are in $A$,  such that $ab = c$ Then $ N(a) N(b) = N(c)$ ( So $N$ is a multiplicative homomorphism )

Let $B$ be a commutative ring.

Usually we take $N$ to be integers.

But When $N$ is defined as elements of $B$, and $B$ is the smallest ring such that Every (element of) $ N $ lies in $B$

Then

Conjecture

$B$ is always a subring of $A$.

Is this conjecture true ? How to prove or disprove it ? Are there easy counterexamples ?

Comment: What do you mean with "multiplicative norm", an absolute value or just a multiplicative homomorphism ? Anyway $|.| : \mathbf{F}_p[x] \to \mathbb{Z}, |f|=p^{-\deg(f)}$. See non-Archimedian absolute values, and their completions.

Comment: @Mick Please state your question.

Comment: See my edit I Just made.

Comment: Im not familiar with nonarchimedean absolute values btw